# Install Android OS on ARM Cortex-M3

Tags: android, operating-system, arm, cortex-m, lpc

Can we install Android OS on ARM Cortex-M3? Here's [ARM community](https://community.arm.com/thread/5552) link that answer to this question but it's not clear. I want to install Android on LPC1788, Is it possible? Any experience?

Comment: Cortex M3 lacks the MMU required to support Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible cause cortex m3 is not for such heavy os , you have to use cortex A series like cortex A53 ,but if you want an os you can use uclinux ,uc/os II ,vxworks on that in which uclinux is opensource

Answer (score 1):

The answer in a nutshell: you can't, because Android runs on A-profile cores, such as Cortex-A9 or Cortex-A15 while M-profile cores such as the Cortex-M3 would be too slow for it. There is a project to port linux to M3, more about it here:

http://www.linux-arm.org/LinuxKernel/LinuxM3

Answer (score 0):

There was previously a project to run Android on an HP iPAQ h3900: https://translate.google.ca/translate?hl=en&sl=hu&u=http://blog.sancho.hu/2010/05/hp-ipaq-h3900-android-port-mukodik.html&prev=search.

This device uses an SA1110 processor.

> The SA-1110 was available in 133 or 206 MHz versions... It was used in mobile phones, personal data assistants (PDAs) such as the Compaq (later HP) iPAQ and HP Jornada, the Sharp SL-5x00 Linux Based Platforms and the Simputer. (From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StrongARM#SA-1110))

Recently, ST has released their [STM32H7 processor](http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32h7-series.html) (Cortex-M7). This processor can run at a 400 MHz rate, faster than the SA1110. So, it might be plausible to run Android on a dev, if you used μcLinux and external RAM/flash.

However, running this on a slower Cortex-M3/4 probably will not work.